# How to provide dynamically calculated data in table using react and redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

How to use redux and react to render dynamically calculated data using function from refux?
In more details: I am trying to render table with two columns (name, share).
Name comes from entity.name and share is calculated data using entity.id and remote service. Currently I have dynamically rendered table with rows per entity with it's name, but I am unable to pass calculated data by entity.id.

I've tried use redux action to do that, but now I understand that redux actions does not return any value, but modifies states in it's store. The code I provided below using {calculateShare(entity.id)} gives me error that it returns array {type, payload}.
Another option might be to build key/value array in redux store and use it in the react table by getting array value using entity.id as a key, but I'm not sure how to do that properly in a reducer and react code.

Reducer looks like this:

```
export const getCalculatedShareById: IPayloadResult<String> = id => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/${id}/calculated-share`;
  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ENTITY_CALCULATED_SHARE,
    payload: axios.get<String>(requestUrl)
  };
};
```

My react example for Home page using reducer:

```
export class Home extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getEntities();
  }

  render() {
    const { entitiesList, getCalculatedShareById } = this.props;
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Share</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {entitiesList.map((entity, i) => (
                <tr key={`entity-${i}`}>
                  <td>{entity.name}</td>
                  <td>{getCalculatedShareById(entity.id)}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = storeState => ({
  entitiesList: storeState.myReducer.entities
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getEntities, getCalculatedShareById};

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);
```

Please help me understand what is the best way to resolve such problem and provide some examples if possible.

Comment: You posted your action, not your reducer. Please post your reducer aswell.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1499 it's not a good practice to store map structure inside redux state, if I understood it correctly. They suggest to use https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with creating web service method which calculates share amount per entity, puts this data to map and returns to react using axios and redux. Not sure if this is the best solution to my problem, but it works.

Example of my working code =>
reducer:

```
export const ACTION_TYPES = {
  FETCH_ENTITY_SHARE_AMOUNT: 'entity/FETCH_ENTITY_SHARE_AMOUNT'
};

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  errorMessage: null,
  entitiesShareAmountMap: Map,
  updating: false,
  updateSuccess: false
};

export type EntityState = Readonly<typeof initialState>;

// Reducer

export default (state: EntityState = initialState, action): EntityState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ENTITY_SHARE_AMOUNT):
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: null,
        updateSuccess: false,
        loading: true
      };
    case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ENTITY_SHARE_AMOUNT):
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        updating: false,
        updateSuccess: false,
        errorMessage: action.payload
      };
    case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ENTITY_SHARE_AMOUNT):
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        entitiesShareAmountMap: action.payload.data
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const apiUrl = 'api/entities';

// Actions

export const getEntitiesShareAmountMap: IPayloadResult<any> = () => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/entities-share-amount`;
  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ENTITY_SHARE_AMOUNT,
    payload: axios.get<Map<String, String>>(requestUrl)
  };
};
```

react component:

```
export class Home extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getEntities();
    this.props.getEntitiesShareAmountMap();
  }

  render() {
    const { entitiesList, entitiesShareAmountMap } = this.props;
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Share</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {entitiesList.map((entity, i) => (
                <tr key={`entity-${i}`}>
                  <td>{entity.name}</td>
                  <td>{entitiesShareAmountMap[lottery.id]}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = storeState => ({
  entitiesList: storeState.myReducer.entities,
  entitiesShareAmountMap: storeState.myReducer.entitiesShareAmountMap
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getEntities, getEntitiesShareAmountMap };

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);
```

Comment: The problems would start, if I need to get value by two identifiers, let say entity id and country code. This would require to have a Map<countryCd, Map<entityId, shareAmount>> and later retrieve value in JS like that entitiesShareAmountMap['DE'][entity.id].